# Soapui post rest service

Tags: marklogic

Can anyone please provide me a xquery scripts to get data from marklogic database.
Script 1. I want to search a word in the most recent document/file that has been loaded into database.
Script 2.  I want to get all the  URI in the database orderby timestamp.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Question shows no actual thought or effort in learning the domain.

Answer (score 1):

I hate to be the one to break it to you, but it is time for you to learn XQuery. Here are some starting points:

- http://developer.marklogic.com/try/corona/index
- http://developer.marklogic.com/try/ninja/index